# Missing directory after move to a link

Tags: linux, directory, solaris, zfs

I have the following dir structure

```
zfs filesystem - /opt/test/tmp
zfs filesystem - /opt/data/
```

I have two directory links:

```
/opt/test2/_tmp -> /opt/test/tmp
/opt/test2/_tmp2 -> /opt/data
```

In /opt/test2/_tmp there was another directory:

```
/opt/test2/_tmp/mydata
```

I was sitting in /opt/test2/_tmp and issued this command:

```
   mv mydata ../_tmp2
```

expecting it to be moved to /opt/data since _tmp2 is a link to it.

But, the folder disappeared completely.  It didn't move to /opt/data and it didn't overwrite the link /opt/test2/_tmp2, but it no longer shows up in /opt/test/_tmp.

So, where did it go, and how do I get it back?

The space on disk hasn't changed, so I know the data is still there.

This is on Solaris 11.4 ZFS, but my guess is conceptually whatever happened would apply to any UNIX/Linux variant.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

I found it...

The mv placed it in /opt/test.  So it took the ../ as a reference to the source directory of the link I was in, rather than that of the link.

Definitely not what I would have expected, but I suppose it makes sense.